# Unable to install pear on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: php

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and a `sudo apt install php-pear` returns :

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.1/php8.1-xml_8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: x.x.x.x 80]
```

This is a 404 - http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.1/php8.1-xml_8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to packages.ubuntu.com, the current version is not `8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10`. It's `...2.11`

The most common cause (by far!) is that the local package database is stale.

Run `sudo apt update` to *update* your local package database.